# The term 'Write-PSFMessage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the virtual machine name for logging purposes

```
Set-PSFLoggingProvider -Name logfile -Enabled $true -FilePath 'C:\PDS\++Scripts++\++logs++\replication_logs.log'

$Hosts = "server01","server02"

ForEach ($Server in $Hosts){
    Write-Host 'Primary Server: '$Server
    $VMName             
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server {
    $FailedReplicas = Get-VMReplication | Where{$_.Health -EQ 'Normal'}
        ForEach ($VM in $FailedReplicas){
            $VMName = $VM.Name
            Write-Host 'Virtual Machine: '$VMName 
            try{
                Resume-VMReplication $VMName -Resynchronize
                Write-Host 'Successfully resynched ' $VMName
                Write-PSFMessage -Level Important -Message 'Successfully resynched ' $VMName  -Tag 'Success'
            }
            catch{
                Write-PSFMessage -Level Warning -Message 'Could not resync ' $VMName -Tag 'Failure' -ErrorRecord $_
            }
        }   
    }   
}
pause
```

When I ran the above code, I get this error
The term 'Write-PSFMessage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: what module is `Write-PSFMessage` from? I think it's no standard cmdlet from microsoft. In that case you would need to import the module on the remote servers before it can be used...

Comment: I found that Write-PSFMessage is from the PSFramework of the Powershell Gallery. Did you install this module? (Install-Module -Name PSFramework)

Comment: Going to guess the module might be present as `Set-PSFLoggingProvider` is from the same location. Perhaps they have an older version that existed before `Write-PSFMessage`. At a minimum its not working because that cmdlet does not exist in your PowerShell session

Comment: @T-Me  just like @Mike said it's from the PSFramework and yes I did `Install-Module -Name PSFramework` already.

@Matt yes the module is present but how do I make it available in the current session because I even did `import-module PSFramework` at the top of the file

Comment: The `Import-Module` has to be in the scriptblock of `Invoke-Command`

Comment: I installed the `PSFramework` on the remote servers and imported the module in the `-ScriptBlock` as @T-Me mentioned and it works now. I will provide the solution soon. Thank you all for your time

Comment: # I feel this can still be done properly because especially regarding where the logs are written to I don't see the logs yet. For now, I am glad I got rid of the error

Answer (score 0):

```
$Hosts = "server01","server02"

ForEach ($Server in $Hosts){
    Write-Host 'Primary Server: '$Server
    $VMName             
    try {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {
            Import-module PSFramework
            $logPath = "\\x.x.x.123\C$\PDS\++Scripts++\++logs++\replication_logs.log"
            Set-PSFLoggingProvider -Name logfile -Enabled $true -FilePath $logPath
            $FailedReplicas = Get-VMReplication | Where{$_.Health -EQ 'Critical'}
            ForEach ($VM in $FailedReplicas){
                $VMName = $VM.Name
                Write-Host 'Virtual Machine: '$VMName 
                Resume-VMReplication $VMName -Resynchronize 
                Write-Host 'Successfully resynched ' $VMName
                Write-PSFMessage -Level Important -Message 'Successfully resynched'  -Target $VMName  -Tag 'Success'                
            } 
        }

    } catch {
        Write-PSFMessage -Level Warning -Message 'Could not resync ' -Tag 'Failure' -ErrorRecord $_
    }
}
pause
```